# Why this code in python gives this error? TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() but i'm calling it on a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, typeerror

This code throws these error:

```
while len(digits) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

but my variable digits is a list right? i guess there must be something i dont understand on list-comprehensions

```
def per(n):

    if len(str(n)) == 1:
        return n

    else:
        digits = [int(i) for i in str(n)]

        count = 1
        while len(digits) > 1: # TypeError:object of type 'int' has no len()

            result = 1
            for j in digits:
                result *= j
        
            digits = result
            count += 1

    return count

print(per(716235))
```

Comment: inside the loop you change digits from a list to a number

Comment: You calculate the result which is an (int) then assign it to digits which make digits become an int(), hence the error

Comment: mistery solved lol, thanks.

Comment: simply use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you really have in variables before line which makes problem. You think you have list but `print()` will show you that you have `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def per(n):

    if len(str(n)) == 1:
        return n

    else:
        digits = [int(i) for i in str(n)]

        count = 1
        while len(digits) > 1:

            result = 1
            for j in digits:
                result *= j
        
            digits = result # <-------- Right here you are setting digits
                            # <-------- as result which is an integer
            count += 1

    return count

print(per(716235))
```